# how to extract date from string in sql oracle 9i

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

I have column Explanation (VARCHAR2) in table:

```
No| Explanation  
1 | Shipment of cabbage by agreement 29.04.2019 TAX Free  
2 | Payment for screws (01.04.19) Tax: 13.55 %  
3 | For reserch by deal dated 01.01.2015 Tax free  
4 | Tax payment for the may 2019
```

I need query thats will answer "Does entry have a date in some form in it?" Yes / No for each entry. Is it possible on Oracle 9i?

I tried some solutions. But run into issue:

> "ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected".

I don't clearly now where datestamp will be in field.

`select to_char(to_date(EXPLANATION, 'DD.MM.YYYY')) from PAYMENTDOC`

Comment: You need to extract the part of _Explanation_ that contains the date string, for example from value `Shipment of cabbage by agreement 29.04.2019 TAX Free` you need to extract `29.04.2019` and send that string to function `to_date()`. Do you know how to extract the relevant part of the column value? Also from this value: `Tax payment for the may 2019` are you supposed to extract `may 2019`?

Comment: Quite strange requirement. What about a messages like "Tax payment for the current year"?

Comment: "Do you know how to extract the relevant part of the column value?" This is where I run into issue. It can be everywhere in field. 
"What about a messages like "Tax payment for the current year"?" I now than it can be: “DD.MM.YYYY’, “DD.MM.YY” and “literal month YYYY”. It can be other weird variations, but which I listed is 80% of fields.

Comment: @Rasinger is there at most one date info in each row for explanation column ?

Comment: It is possible to contain more than one date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using regular expression. Try below code :

```
  select No, Explanation, 
  case when regexp_instr(Explanation,'\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2}')!=1 then 
              'Y'
              when regexp_instr(Explanation,'\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}')!=1 then
              'Y'
              when REGEXP_instr(Explanation, '(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) [0-9]{4}')!=1 then
              'Y'
             END Does_entry_have_a_date_in_some_form_in_it
  from table_name;
```

Output :

```
No| Explanation                                          | Does_entry_have_a_date_in_some_form_in_it
1 | Shipment of cabbage by agreement 29.04.2019 TAX Free | Y
2 | Payment for screws (01.04.19) Tax: 13.55 %           | Y
3 | For reserch by deal dated 01.01.2015 Tax free        | Y
4 | Tax payment for the may 2019                         | Y
```

Comment: Unfortunately oracle 9i doesn't have regular expressions(

Comment: So I found some way to use (regexp_instr) as function - http://oracleappstech-vinoth.blogspot.com/2012/03/regexpinstr-function-for-oracle-9i.html. Now it working.